# Printing Traditional Chinese Characters on escpos-python with Minimum Documentation

Tags: python, escpos

I am still new to escpos programming so bear with me if there is a stupid mistake and such.

I would be glad if anyone could show me how to print out traditional chinese characters using escpos python library on printer ec-pm-80330 which I can only found the feature list online http://www.ecline.com.hk/admin/upload/product/dataSheet/64.pdf.

I have been brute-forcing the printing with different type of encoding and trying to switch on kanji mode with no avail.

Here is one of my attempts (simplified) on solving my problem.

```
from escpos import printer as escpos_printer
from escpos.constants import FS, NUL

menu = {'name': "你好"}

printer = escpos_printer.Serial(devfile=comport)

printer.textln('Test GB18030')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('GB18030'))
printer.ln(1)

printer.textln('Test UTF8')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('utf8'))
printer.ln(1)

printer.charcode(code='CP850')
printer.textln('Test CP850 - raw')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('utf8'))
printer.ln(1)

printer.textln('Test CP850 - text')
printer.textln(menu['name'])
printer.charcode(code='AUTO')

printer.textln('Test normal')
printer.textln(menu['name'])


# Turned on kanji mode
printer.textln('Kanji mode on')
printer._raw(FS + '!'.encode('ascii') + NUL)
printer.textln('Test GB18030')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('GB18030'))
printer.ln(1)

printer.textln('Test UTF8')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('utf8'))
printer.ln(1)
        
printer.charcode(code='CP850')
printer.textln('Test CP850 - raw')
printer._raw(menu['name'].encode('utf8'))
printer.ln(1)

printer.textln('Test CP850 - text')
printer.textln(menu['name'])
printer.charcode(code='AUTO')

printer.textln('Test normal')
printer.textln(menu['name'])

printer._raw(FS + '.'.encode('ascii'))
```

I have also tried using gbk and big5, which all of them gives out either '?' or gibberish in the printed result, but other than the chinese characters, it works fine.

There are actually some commands listed at the back of the printer which I am not really sure if it can help me solve this problem.

[Commands at the back of the printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ7Mo.jpg)

Looking from the other answers in stack overflow/github did not help me much but I would be nice if anyone is willing to give me an explanation on which part I missed or was mistaken.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seems to be tools such as language setting here. [Utility tools](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ixaezufqbblh0td/AAD7diJR_RAyzmbnq6jutItOa?dl=0) Why not give this a try?

Comment: @kunif I am not quite sure what Utility tools is for. I suppose it is used to change the configuration of the printer? I currently don't have the physical printer, so I am trying to gain as much info as possible before trying on the printer.

Comment: Probably the quickest way is to ask the vendor or reseller.

Comment: @kunif thanks for the reply! Apparently, the machine's chip does not have chinese compactibility, and the vendor gave us an offer to switch the chip to a compactible one. So all ends well XD.